# Android and AdMob ad not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

I am having issues integrating AdMob into my android app. When I start the activity the ad layout appears blank.

After going through these documentations [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start?hl=en-GB#import_the_mobile_ads_sdk) my ads does not seem to appear.

I am able to display test ad without any trouble using `ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111`.

Here is my simple implementation:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AdView adView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adView = findViewById(R.id.ad_view);

        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

                // Start loading the ad in the background.
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/masterLayout"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="MEDIUM_RECTANGLE"
        app:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-6259429743173109~6260380386"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'

}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <!-- Strings used for fragments for navigation -->
    <string name="first_fragment_label">First Fragment</string>
    <string name="second_fragment_label">Second Fragment</string>

    <!-- Test ad -->
    <!-- <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string> -->

    <!-- Actual ad -->
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-6259429743173109/1030080916</string>

</resources>
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the LogCat for messages?

Comment: You can't show ads except the test in the debug mode, ads shows only on the release mode

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to display test ads and not the real ads then there is no problem in your code the problem is with your admob account. Check if that banner ad unit id exist if yes then they might be monitoring your traffic So fill this form to appeal to admob support for ad not showing and it will be fixed within a week.
[Form link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScmja8eUJDJlkXtmM9C0868TmRwgOZp7pupLBETgYmGcbuLzQ/viewform)